# I don't really understand the DOM standard Event object

Tags: javascript, jquery

right now I'm trying to learn JavaScript with the book "Beginning JavaScript 5th Edition" and because english is not my native language it's sometimes hard to understand.

Right now I'm a bit confused with the so called **DOM standard Event object**.

```
function handleEvent(e) {
  var target = e.target; 
  var type = e.type;


  if (target.tagName == "P") { 
    if (type == "mouseover") {
      target.className = "underline"; } else if (type == "mouseout") {
      target.className = ""; }
 } 
};
```

Is **e** just a convention for a parameter that I could give any name I want ? For example y ?

Can I think of **.target** as the same as **.this** ?

**.target** references to my element on which an event occurs, right ?

Comment: _"Is e just a convention for a parameter that I could give any name I want ? For example y ?

Can I think of .target as the same as .this ?

.target references to my element on which an event occurs, right ?"_ Yes. Though `this` instead of `.this`

Comment: `event.target` can be different than `this`. `this` refers to element at which event is bound (except in case of delegation where jq set it as the current target) while `event.target` refers to element which initiate event. Most event bubbles, that's why they can be different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`e` is just a convention for the parameter, and so is `event`. Because `e` has all the `event` propertys. Try outputting `e` in your console, and you'll see all the values it has. (Btw, `e` is just an object as you'll see in your console.)

In your `handleEvent` function, just add `console.log(e)` to see everything it has.

`e.target` is the element which the event is called on. And `e.type` is the event type. If you switch `e` to `event` things might become clearer to you.

Comment: So just to be clear. I could aswell each time write: event.target ?

Comment: @UnknownUser Yes, you can. But for (I think) performance, and readability reasons, it is better to create a variable if you're going to use it more than one time.

Comment: @UnknownUser Let me know if you have anymore questions on the answer I wrote, or in JavaScript programming in general.

Comment: I think I understand it better now thanks to you:) But the console throws me an error no matter what. "e is not defined"..

Comment: @UnknownUser Happy to hear you understand it better now. You would have to show me the rest of the code (i.e. how you're calling `handleEvent`) in order for me to be able to figure it out. But, I'm assuming, your'e calling `handleEvent` wrong.

Comment: At the end of the script I simply have following line:     document.addEventListener("click", handleEvent);

Comment: @UnknownUser Please go to http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122546/discussion-between-unknown-user-and-jessica

Comment: @UnknownUser Np! :) Let me know if you understand the sample code from the jsfiddle you posted. Also, if you need any more help, don't hesitate to text me up: (three two three) five one three - two eight one nine (I spelled out my number for security reasons.) Or you can send me an email; which is at my user profile.

Comment: I think I understand it now:)

Answer (score 1):

e is indeed just a convention, so you could give it any name you want. .target is de element that fires the event, so its the element where you attached the event to.

Comment: `target is de element that fires the event, so its the element where you attached the event to` No that *could be* wrong! See e.g: https://jsfiddle.net/7s73pnc4/

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  e is the standard variable name given to the event object.  That variable name could be anything.

Comment: el is the standard variable name for an HTML element that is passed to a function.  It could be anything, too.